# How to solve time dependent coupled differential equations using Floquet method?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, fourier-analysis

I have coupled differential equations

```
D[X[t], t] == M[t] X[t] + R[t]
```

where

```
X[t] = ( {{x1, x2}} )\[Transpose];

M[t] = ( {{0, b[t]\[ConjugateTranspose]},{b[t], a[t]}} );

R[t] = ( {{0, a[t]}} )\[Transpose];

b[t] = b1 E^(-I δ t) + b2 E^(I δ t);
a[t] = a1 E^(-I δ t) + a2 E^(I δ t);
```

If we consider the solution of `X[t]` as harmonic expansion on the elements.

```
  x_m [t] = Sum[X_m^{n}[t] Exp[i n δ t], {n,-10,10}]
```

Want to solve above differential equation using [Floquet method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory).

To plot elements of `x[t]`, we can consider `a1=b1=1, a2=b2=2`

Comment: You're missing a `Dot` in the differential equation. What have you tried?

Comment: Since `b[t]` is a scalar, use ` b[t]\[Conjugate]` instead of ` b[t]\[ConjugateTranspose]`.

Comment: I do not believe that `X_m^{n}[t]` is syntactically correct.  What are you trying to convey?

Comment: Try to understand Foquet method...

Answer (score 5):

Although this Answer does not use Floquet analysis, it does cast the equations into a more useful form and provide a sample numerical solution.

```
X[t] = {{x1[t], x2[t]}}\[Transpose];
b[t] = b1 E^(-I δ t) + b2 E^(I δ t);
a[t] = a1 E^(-I δ t) + a2 E^(I δ t);
M[t] = {{0, FullSimplify[Conjugate[b[t]], 
            t ∈ Reals && δ ∈ Reals && b1 ∈ Reals && b2 ∈ Reals] // Expand}, 
        {b[t], a[t]}};
R[t] = {{0, a[t]}}\[Transpose];

eq = (# == 0) & /@ (D[X[t], t] - M[t].X[t] - R[t])
(* {{-(b2 E^(-I t δ) + b1 E^(I t δ)) x2[t] + Derivative[1][x1][t]} == 0,
    {-a1 E^(-I t δ) - a2 E^(I t δ) - (b1 E^(-I t δ) + b2 E^(I t δ)) x1[t] - 
      (a1 E^(-I t δ) + a2 E^(I t δ)) x2[t] + Derivative[1][x2][t]} == 0} *)

{s1, s2} = NDSolveValue[{eq /. {a1 -> 1, a2 -> 1, b1 -> 1, b2 -> 1, δ -> 1}, 
             x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1}, {x1, x2}, {t, - 2 Pi, 2 Pi}];
Plot[{s1[t], s2[t]}, {t, - 2 Pi, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"δ t", "X"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 12}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The Fourier series coefficients can be obtained for these curves in a straightforward manner.  For `s1`, for instance,

```
Needs["FourierSeries`"]
c1 = Table[NFourierCoefficient[s1[t], t, n], {n, 0, 20}];
ListLogPlot[{Abs[Re[c1]], Abs[Im[c1]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Mode amplitudes become negligible for mode numbers greater than about 11, and reconstruction of the original `s1` is accurate to a relative accuracy of about `10^-5` for `11` modes.  Similar results hold for `s2`.

Comment: The solution does look periodic; I guess that's why OP wants to see the Fourier series solution…